# Consultar los registros de un campo en SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Necesito conocer la cantidad de registros que tiene un campo en SQL SERVER 2008. Si ejecuto la sentencia:

```
select count(*) from 'tabla'
```

el resultado que me arroja es 996.561

pero si ejecuto la sentencia:

```
select count(e-mail) from 'tabla'
```

el resultado que me arroja es 996.561 (la misma cantidad que si contara todos los registros)

Ya he revisado el campo manualmente y se que muchos de mis clientes no registraron su E-mail, ¿entonces por qué me arroja el mismo resultado?

Comment: Cuando un usuario no registra su email, ¿cual es el valor en el campo? ¿Es realmente null?  ¿O es una cadena vacía?  Porque si es una cadena vacía, el `count` los va a contar.

Comment: cuando no se registra E-mail el campo llega vacío. La función NULLIFF fue la solución. Mil gracias por la Observación.

Comment: Hola Felipe, no te olvides aceptar la respuesta de Mean24 entonces.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función NULLIF para que si el campo es una cadena vacía lo tome como nulo y no lo incluya en tu consulta:

```
    SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(email, '')) FROM 'Tabla'
```